# Use purrr to map to 2 functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have data of the following form

```
   date                  data              
   <chr>                <list>            
 1 2012-01-05           <tibble [796 x 5]>
 2 2012-01-12           <tibble [831 x 5]>
 3 2012-01-19           <tibble [820 x 5]>
 ...                       ...
```

I would like to use something analogous to `map()` to calculate the mean and standard deviation.

I can currently use the following separately, but it is possible to calculate both at the same time.

```
mutate(stats = map(data, ~ sd(.$metric)))
mutate(stats = map(data, ~ mean(.$metric)))
```

Another alternative is to make a function that is like `summary`, which returns quartiles and the mean. but calculate the `mean` and `sd` instead. then I could use that new function in `map` as follows:

```
mutate(stats = map(data, ~ new_function(.$metric)))
```

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option to add multiple columns is to just make another list column of the desired summary statistics and `unnest` it:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

df <- data_frame(date = seq(as.Date('1970-01-01'), by = 1, length = 4), 
                 data = map(date, ~data_frame(metric = rnorm(10))))

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   date       data             
#>   <date>     <list>           
#> 1 1970-01-01 <tibble [10 × 1]>
#> 2 1970-01-02 <tibble [10 × 1]>
#> 3 1970-01-03 <tibble [10 × 1]>
#> 4 1970-01-04 <tibble [10 × 1]>

df %>% 
    mutate(stats = map(data, ~data.frame(mean = mean(.x$metric), 
                                         sd = sd(.x$metric)))) %>% 
    unnest(stats)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   date       data                mean    sd
#>   <date>     <list>             <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1970-01-01 <tibble [10 × 1]> -0.106 0.992
#> 2 1970-01-02 <tibble [10 × 1]> -0.102 0.875
#> 3 1970-01-03 <tibble [10 × 1]> -0.833 0.979
#> 4 1970-01-04 <tibble [10 × 1]>  0.184 0.671
```

A more programmatic approach (which may scale better) is to iterate within the anonymous function over a list of functions. `lst` will automatically name them, so the results will be named, and `map_dfc` will cbind them into a data frame:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(stats = map(data, 
                       ~map_dfc(lst(mean, sd), 
                                function(.fun) .fun(.x$metric)))) %>% 
    unnest(stats)
```

purrr has a purpose-built function for iterating over functions/parameters like this: `invoke_map`. If you want the function or parameters to be recycled, they have to be in a length-1 list. Since parameters should already be collected in a list, here it has to be a nested list.

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(stats = map(data, 
                       ~invoke_map_dfc(lst(mean, sd), 
                                       list(list(.x$metric))))) %>% 
    unnest(stats)
```

All approaches return the same thing.